# How can I select the second-to-last rows in a mysql table, grouped by column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Structure is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE current
(
   id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(id),
   symbol VARCHAR(5),
   UNIQUE (id), INDEX (symbol)
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

| id | symbol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | C |
| 8 | C |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | B |

I am using the following

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM current
WHERE id
IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM current
    GROUP BY symbol
)
```

to return the last records in a table.

| id | symbol |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | C |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | B |

How can I return the next-to-last results in a similar fashion?

I know that I need

```sql
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

somewhere, but my foo is weak.

I would want to return

| id | symbol |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | C |

Comment: Maybe you need the TOP 2, and then LIMIT 1 to get first of 2 top results. Of course you have to get order in mind. I don't know the dataset, but I think it will be useful for your logic

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Care to elaborate with an example? mysql is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions of MySql prior to 8.0, use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to filter out the max `id` of each symbol and then aggregate:

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, symbol
FROM current
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM current GROUP BY symbol)
GROUP BY symbol
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e273681a604f566e83cacad0c1ffb2d9).

Comment: This appears to work the fastest, but if I were to add another column to the table (say, TIMESTAMP), the columns are correct for id and symbol, but TIMESTAMP looks to be coming from the first row.

Comment: @weirdbeard you can't add columns in an aggregation query. Even if it runs (most databases would not even accept it), the column values would arbitrary. If you want other columns you can do something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ad27e2f7b8dc363fd039dc59be24b1b1

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM current
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT T.id FROM current AS T
  WHERE id=(
    SELECT id FROM current
    WHERE symbol=T.symbol
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however these only return the second-to-last row of the table, not all rows grouped by 'symbol.'

Comment: @weirdbeard I've edited my code. Does it work?

Comment: It appears to have worked but took 5 minutes to complete. The table has several million records.

Answer (score 0):

Easy if your MySql can use ROW_NUMBER. (MySql 8)
Just make it sort descending, then take the 2nd.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY id DESC) AS symbol_rn
    FROM current
) 
SELECT id, symbol
FROM CTE
WHERE symbol_rn = 2
ORDER BY id;
```

In MySql 7.5 you can simply self-join on the symbol, and group by.
Then the 2nd last will have 1 higher id.

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.symbol
FROM current c1
LEFT JOIN current c2
  ON c2.symbol = c1.symbol
 AND c2.id >= c1.id
GROUP BY c1.id, c1.symbol
HAVING COUNT(c2.id) = 2
ORDER BY c1.id;
```

| id | symbol |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=221eb1525185c82fe0ac9e4533c63a3c)*

The performance will really benefit from an index on symbol.

Comment: Your first solution (MySql 8) returns results as expected and is the best answer so far.

I do have an index on symbol, however the query is still taking around 11 seconds to run.

Comment: Interesting, not sure how you can speed it up though. Btw, how fast is the 2nd solution then?

Comment: I'll let you know when it finishes ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM current
WHERE id
IN (SELECT MAX(id)
FROM current
GROUP BY symbol)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,3
```

limit 1,3 says; get the last 3 results excluding the last result. You can change the numbers.

Comment: This does not return the OP's expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=abc0096a8e8da7d53486469e36c51fc7

Comment: I think because we are using group by, it gave that result in the example in the link. Change the symbol of the data with id value 7 to D and try again

Comment: No, it is because your answer is wrong.

Comment: it depends on where you are looking at the question

Comment: No, it depends on understanding the requirement and understanding what your code does. If you see that the results that you get from your code are not what they should be then you know that you are wrong.

Comment: my code is doing what i say. When i'm writing code for this question, this question was not like this. Anyway, thank you!